# echoing thumbnails that link to the larger image

Tags: php, navigation, thumbnails

I have a script that scans a directory of thumbnails and echoes them to the page. It works nicely, but the thumbnails are not clickable, and i would really like this to be the case. `echo "<img src='$thumbnail' class='resizesmall'>";`   is the line where the thumbnails are echoed. I'm not sure how to write the path to the larger image inside the php without breaking it. Maybe this should be done inside the foreach statement? thanks for your help?

```
$dir = "../mysite/thumbnails/";
$dh = opendir($dir);

// echo "$dh";
$gallery = array();
while($filename = readdir($dh))
{
$filepath = $dir.$filename;

//pregmatch used to be ereg
if (is_file($filepath) and preg_match("/\.png/",$filename))
{
$gallery[] = $filepath;
}
}
sort($gallery);
foreach($gallery as $thumbnail)
{
echo "<img src='$thumbnail' class='resizesmall'>";
}
?>
</div>
<??>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to setup a situation where your thumbs and your full size images were named the same. So you may have thumbs/image1.png and full/image1.png. Then instead of using $thumbnail use a variable $image, or something similar just so the code reads better. You'll also want to leave the $filepath out of the mix so that $image ends up as just the file name.

```
foreach($gallery as $image)
{
    echo "<a href='full/$image'><img src='thumb/$image' class='resizesmall'></a>";
}
```

You may want to throw in some checks to make sure there is a matching image just to prevent errors or bad UX. However, the code above should work.

Comment: take $filepath out of the script entirely? it seems to be breaking it.  doesn't it need it?

Comment: Basically the way the original script was it was building an array that included both the file path and the file name so that the variable $thumbnail would be equal to "path/to/filename" etc. However in order to correctly link to both the thumb and full size image by name you don't want the file path be used in the for each loop, you just want your variable to be equal to the file name. So you still need $filepath, but only for the reading of the files in your thumb directory. Sorry for not clarifying that a bit better.

Comment: i changed $gallery[] = $filepath; to
$gallery[] = $filename;, seems to work fine.